# DotNetNuke 'TrueFalse' profile property labels

Tags: dotnetnuke

By default, DotNetNuke 'TrueFalse' Profile Property displays two radio buttons with 'True' and 'False' labels. Is there a way to rename these labels so that they say something like 'Yes' and 'No', for instance?

Like this: http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/5773/profileproperty.jpg

It seems a little bit odd that user profile properties have boolean labels, so I'm assuming this must be somehow customizable. I just can't see how...

Answer (score 0):

Customizing almost any label in DNN is done through the localization (language) features in the portal. I would look on the wiki on the DNN site for specifics (I am not sure where the labels you are looking at are)

Answer (score 0):

You can do by setting or just change the TrueFalse data type default label using jquery.

I have used the same procedure for one of my project.

```
var genderCount = 1;
$('#dnn_ctr632_Register_userForm_a304ec533c1ae2f23db908fa1cc294c5 .dnnFormInput').each(function () {
        if (genderCount===1)
            $(this).html('Women');
        else {
            $(this).html('Men');
        }
        genderCount++;
    });
```